# Why I am obtaining this error message trying to register the FireFox action on Google.com using JMeter?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am absolutly new in Jmeter and I have the following problem.

I succesfully recorded the navigation on some websites into a **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** Non Test element.

Then I was trying to record the navigation on **Google** so I used the same approach, these are the steps:

```
- Add --> Non Test Element --> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.
- Test Plan Creation TAB --> Target Controller: Test Plan > HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.
- Request Filter TAB --> Add suggested Excludes (exludes all the images,etcetc not needed for test pourpose).
- Set proxy on browser 127.0.0.1:8888 for all the protocols.
- Install JMeter certificate in Firefox.
- Start recording.
- Open a website.
- Stop recording.
```

The strange thing is that, differently from the other registered website, trying to access to the Google main page I obtain the following error message into FireFox:

There is an error during the connection with www.google.com

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add HTTP Request Defaults ?

Comment: @user7294900 Where? what do you exaclty mean?

Comment: In test plan. See https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as you are recording `HTTPS` site. JMeter itself generates certificates that needs to be trusted by the browser.

Check here for more info - section `Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording`http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder